# ssh2 how base 'G' and modulus 'P' are negociated, unknown field

Tags: ssh, wireshark, public-key-encryption, diffie-hellman

(first at all i'm sorry for my English because it is not my native language)
I try to understand ssh2 with wireshark(you can find the wireshark record here : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/e9ut8z6v8oldg7g/ssh_wireshark.pcap?token_hash=AAGtkPMwKLt4IIr1Rlrht5_21HpMwQZBfeEFjGoRA85cjQ&dl=1) and rfc 4253 but i have some difficulties:

After SSH_MSG_KEXINIT messages there is SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT (30) and SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY (31).

my problem is the understanding of SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT and SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY.
According to the rfc4253:

```
First, the client sends the following:

  byte      SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
  mpint     e

The server then responds with the following:

  byte      SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
  string    server public host key and certificates (K_S)
  mpint     f
  string    signature of H
```

but with wireshark i see:

```
from Client:

-SSH Version 2 (encryption:aes128-ctr mac:hmac-md5 compression:none)
    Packet Length: 76
    Padding Length: 5
    -Key Exchange
            Msg Code: Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange Init (30)
            Payload: 0000004104e2d6ad26e76531efa9ea(...)
            Padding String: 0000000000




from Server:
-SSH Version 2 (encryption:aes128-ctr mac:hmac-md5 compression:none)
    Packet Length: 292
    Padding Length: 8
    -Key Exchange
            Msg Code: Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange Reply (31)
            Multi Precision Integer Length: 104
            DH modulus (P): 0000001365636473612d73686(...)
            Multi Precision Integer Length: 65
            DH base (G): 04ead7f3936361df10c39d7d(...)
            Payload: 000000650000001365636473612d(...)
            Padding String: 0000000000000000
```

what are 'payload' fields? how base 'G' and modulus 'P' are negociated? an ecdsa public key is prime or composite number?

this is my analyze:

a)wireshark is wrong.

If rfc is right, payloads field are 'e' and 'f'!

But there is a problem : if rfc is right, modulus p and base g have to be known BEFORE SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT because we need them to compute 'e'; so the wireshark decoding is wrong because wireshark tell me that P and G are transmit AFTER SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT.

and there is something else telling me wireshark is wrong : if i decode the base64 that i can find in the /etc/....pub file, i can see the value of wireshark DH_modulus field.
So DH_modulus field is not really DH_modulus but server public host key : rfc is right, wireshark is wrong!

In this case base and modulus are not transmit by "Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange Reply" so how 'g' and 'p' are transmitted??are they "prefixed" in all ssh client/server and never transmitted?

b)wireshark is right

if we suppose server public host key is a prime number it can be DH_modulus and rfc AND wireshark are right.

but in this, there is again a problem : payload from client can't be 'e' because payload is transmit before DH_modulus and DH_base...

so what are the payload field?

when 'e' and 'f' are sent? because just after "Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange Reply" i have "Newkeys messages" which indicate the end of key exchange

but on other hand i have 4 packets to/from port 22 which are not decoded as ssh but it is maybe "e" and "f"??

first two packet are 48 bytes length and the 2 others are 64bytes length.

are 'e' and 'f' transmitted in these 4 tcp packets ? maybe e and f are 64+48=112 bytes length?

as you can see i'm in confusion. can you help me (maybe not for all question but some indications can help)

thank you.

Comment: the 4 packets are encrypted packets actually( and they appears after new_key message). so it can't be 'e' and 'f'. don't care about the history of these 4 packets! sorry about that!

Answer (score 2):

In this case it's Wireshark incorrectly interpreting the public key algorithm.  Packet number 13 which came from the server is properly formatted according to RFC5656 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5656).  It's using the ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 algorithm which is an elliptic curve algorithm with 2 variables: q and r.

Wireshark is improperly parsing this packet using a different RFC (although not strictly 4253).  RFC5656 section 3.1 will give you the information you need to get on the right track.  For your information I'll post variables r and s in this response.

In reality, the information contained is:

Server's public host key (string K_S):
string  "ecdsa-sha2-nistp256" (where "nistp256" is the [identifier])
byte[n]  ecc_key_blob
string  "nistp256" (repeated again as [identifier] portion of blob)
string   Q (where Q is as follows)

Q (0073-00b3):
04 bb e6 6e 8e   b6 b4 f8 29 8f e2 b1 ba
a0 2f 24 a2 d6 33 74 d4   17 ce b2 17 73 da 95 1a
ac c4 4b d7 a8 fc 92 6d   c6 c1 38 95 a6 5b 1f da
ec d2 29 df 2c 68 5c dc   de 36 bc 8b 34 16 24 28
0c 57 e1 7e

Server's ephemeral public key octet string (string Q_S):

Q_S (00b8-00f8):
04 ea d7 f3 93 63 61 df
10 c3 9d 7d bb ff 4d 38   0d 78 53 ea 00 97 30 b9
f5 cb a0 ea 1f 59 68 5b   c6 c6 de fb a8 16 f6 a9
e2 88 96 d8 e9 48 c4 c3   4a 24 bc 58 7f cd 6e b3
2f 4a 18 ac d7 68 d7 df   0b

Signature on the exchange hash (string):
string  "ecdsa-sha2-nistp256" (again where nistp256 is the [identifier])
string   ecdsa_signature_blob
mpint r (011c-013c):
00 84 0a a1
08 cf e8 2b a9 77 80 f2   82 99 59 e4 bb e4 f0 e8
bf 56 f2 ca 70 7a 4d 53   b0 6e b1 fc 0a

```
           mpint s (0141-0161):
```

00 bb 2a 08 c1 3e 41   ec 27 db 24 e8 1f 57 06
db 55 9f 5d e9 fa 48 87   b2 2e 97 3c 46 59 7a 14
c9 40

Hopefully this helps clear up the confusion.  You'll still have a bit of research to do with RFC5656 and possibly referring back to RFC4253 to fill in the blanks but that is the breakdown of the packet.

Good luck!

Scott in New York, USA